# Internal Hard Disk cannot boot - Unrecognized file system (-69846)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My Internal hard disk won't boot after I closed MacBook by holding powerbutton.

I've created a bootable HD on USB. Disk Utility can see the internal HD, but cannot see any volumes.
Terminal can see the partition disk0s2s, but it has no "Type" (see the screenshot). From my newbie knowledge, I think this is part of the problem (?)
[image]
Sometimes, when using First Aid in Disk Utility, the HD disappears.
I have tried DriveDX, that says everything looks good, and TestDisk without luck.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Does help with this sort of question if you tell us what model MacBook (2015 MBP?) and what version of macOS. Do you have important not backed up data on your internal disk?

Comment: Are you using APFS or HFS+ filesystem? What version of Mac OS are you using for the broken drive?

Comment: Sorry for not pointing that out. 
It's a Apple MacBook Pro 13-Inch "Core i5" 2.7 Early 2015 - MF839LL/A* - A1502.
Running: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (I think) - can't see that now.
Filesystem must have been HFS+ (Mac OS Extended), it's age taken into concern.